# Error with yarn start and ExecCommand.execute

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm having an issue with running my script by using `npm run start` and `yarn start.`

**Below is the output:**

```
C:\Windows\System32\login>npm run start

login-with-metamask@2.0.0 start C:\Windows\System32\login

lerna exec yarn start --parallel

Lerna v2.0.0-beta.20

Errored while running command 'yarn' with arguments 'start' in '@login-with-metamask/backend'

Errored while running ExecCommand.execute

-4058

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! login-with-metamask@2.0.0 start: `lerna exec yarn start --parallel`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the login-with-metamask@2.0.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hafizuddin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-15T18_04_01_680Z-debug.log
```

**Below is the content of my package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "login-with-metamask",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "author": "<hidden>",
  "description": "Demo project for 'One-click Login with Blockchain: A MetaMask Tutorial'",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "repository": "<hidden>",
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/*"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "lerna exec yarn build --parallel",
    "lint": "lerna exec yarn lint --parallel",
    "start": "lerna exec yarn start --parallel",
    "test": "lerna exec yarn test --parallel"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.11",
    "lerna": "2.0.0-beta.20",
    "prettier": "^1.17.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "main": "index.js"
}
```

`npm version: 6.9.0`

`node version: 10.16.3`

`yarn version: 1.17.3`

I've tried updating, installing and reinstalling but the error still occurs. Anyone knows a fix for this?

**EDIT**: Below is the content of the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle login-with-metamask@2.0.0~prestart: login-with-metamask@2.0.0
6 info lifecycle login-with-metamask@2.0.0~start: login-with-metamask@2.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle login-with-metamask@2.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle login-with-metamask@2.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Windows\System32\login\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Hafizuddin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Users\Hafizuddin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Hafizuddin\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle login-with-metamask@2.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Windows\System32\login
10 silly lifecycle login-with-metamask@2.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'lerna exec yarn start --parallel' ]
11 silly lifecycle login-with-metamask@2.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle login-with-metamask@2.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: login-with-metamask@2.0.0 start: `lerna exec yarn start --parallel`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid login-with-metamask@2.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Windows\System32\login
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error login-with-metamask@2.0.0 start: `lerna exec yarn start --parallel`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the login-with-metamask@2.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Can you include the error found in : C:\Users\Hafizuddin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-15T18_04_01_680Z-debug.log

Comment: did you try to run your project directly using node ./app.js?

Comment: @elolelo I have edit the post with the content of the log

Comment: @SamiShamesEl-Deen no, haven't try that yet.